# Converting an array of ints to 1 int

Tags: java

I want to convert an array of ints to 1 int.

e.g. I have an array of ints {1,2,3,4,5} and want to convert it to the int 12345

How do I do this?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hint: 12345 = 1 * 10000 + 2 * 1000 + 3 * 100 + 4 * 10 + 5

Comment: I would probably convert them to strings, add the strings, then convert back to int

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal - it would be helpful to learn how numeric system actually works.

Comment: I would have done it, with StringBuilder, as shown by Kugathasan. However, I'm curious what the advantages and disadvantages of Jesper's commented solution would be. (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the array, and concatenate the values to String and convert that String to int

```
String valueSt = "";
for(int val : array) {
  valueSt += val;
}

int finalValue = Integer.valueOf(valueSt);
```

Comment: Should be `+=`, not `=+`. Better yet, use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Jesper : Sorry, I directly typed the coding, didn't notice it!